# Make a FaceTime call using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, facetime

Is it possible to initiate a FaceTime call with "+1 (###) ###-####" when I execute an AppleScript?

Does FaceTime support AppleScript and how can I automate the start of a call?

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363800/auto-facetime-call-using-applescript-without-confirm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This'll do it. You can input a phone number in most normal formats. Can't say I've tried them all:

```
set phone_num to text returned of (display dialog "Input a phone number to call:" default answer "")
do shell script "open facetime://" & quoted form of phone_num
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until (button "Call" of window 1 of application process "FaceTime" exists)
        delay 1
    end repeat
    click button "Call" of window 1 of application process "FaceTime"
end tell
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with the new notification services in recent macOS versions, this no longer works, just hanging, waiting for a button to appear that never does.

Comment: It works for me still on macOS 10.15.6

Answer (score 1):

Great code William Foggard! Thank you, your code works for me, running Big Sur, 11.4. Here is a slightly modified version. It will FaceTime what you put in for ***********, William's code has a pop up box. It's working well with Keyboard Maestro.

```
do shell script "open facetime://" & "+***********"
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until (button "Call" of window 1 of application process "FaceTime" exists)
        delay 1
    end repeat
    click button "Call" of window 1 of application process "FaceTime"
end tell
```

I wanted to leave this as a comment but looks like I need more points first. This is one of my first posts so hope it turned out ok.