# Making a FaceTime Audio call using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, audio, facetime

I have read through [Make a FaceTime call using AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189774/make-a-facetime-call-using-applescript/189775#189775), but the provided solution is for starting a video call. I am wondering if that solution can be adapted to make a FaceTime Audio call (and by extension, maybe even a call via iPhone utilizing Continuity).

Answer (score 2):

I found it!

I tried many different combinations, such as `facetimeaudio://[phonenumber]` and `facetime://audio/[phonenumber]`, but nothing worked. I was starting to think that there wasn't a way to do this.

However, today, I decided to take another crack at it with some different combos, and this one works: `facetime-audio://[phonenumber]`.

Comment: I also figured out how to make calls via iPhone to take advantage of the Continuity features. It uses the URL scheme `tel://[phonenumber]`.