# Auto FaceTime call using AppleScript, without confirmation

Tags: macos, applescript, mojave, facetime

I would like to automate a FaceTime call without having to confirm the call in the FaceTime app. Is there a way to do that?

EDIT:
[image: Call message]

When I execute the script I get this message in the upper right corner.
I would like to bypass this message so that the call starts automatically.

EDIT2:

[image]
Unfortunately I do not have this option under macOS Mojave 10.14.5

```
set phone_num to "mailxyz@mail.com"
do shell script "open facetime://" & quoted form of phone_num
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until (button "Call" of window 1 of application process "FaceTime" exists)
        delay 1
    end repeat
    click button "Call" of window 1 of application process "FaceTime"
end tell
```

Comment: I added a screenshot to the question. I would like to avoid this message.

Comment: As I previous said, your code, with my info, works for me without issue; however, I'm running it on macOS High Sierra. If with macOS Mojave in FaceTime > Preferences… there is no setting to bypass the Notification Center confirmation, then you'll just have to add the extra AppleScript code to click Call on it.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work under mac OS Mojave and there is no function like this. Do you have an idea how to integrate this into the script? 

Or I just downgrade back to High Sierra. but I'd like to stay on Mojave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **macOS High Sierra** the **Call** *button* in directly on the face of the **FaceTime** *window* and why `click button "Call" of window 1 of application process "FaceTime"` works.

Is this true for **macOS Mojave** too, and then when that *button* is clicked one also gets the **Notification Center** *Alert*, or when placing the call it only shows the **Notification Center** *Alert* with the **Call** *button* on it?

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will wait for **Notification Center** to display a *window* and *click* the **Call** *button*, assuming it has one.

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until (exists window 1 of application process "Notification Center")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click button "Call" of window 1 of application process "Notification Center"
end tell
```

Obviously this does not take into account if there is more then one *notification*, say if one existed prior to the call being made and had not yet been dismissed. In that scenario, additional coding will be necessary to target the specific *notification*.

**Update:** After some additional testing, under **macOS High Sierra**, the previous paragraph may be an unnecessary statement if the result are the same under **macOS Mojave**. The testing revealed that if a *notification* is present when another one is displayed, then the latest *notification* displayed is placed at the top of the *window list* in **Notification Center** and is then `window 1`. In that case, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* may work for you:

```
set phone_num to "mailxyz@mail.com"
do shell script "open facetime://" & quoted form of phone_num
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until (exists window 1 of application process "Notification Center")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click button "Call" of window 1 of application process "Notification Center"
end tell
```

- This *example code* assumes in **macOS Mojave** when placing the call, in this manner, it only shows the **Notification Center** *Alert* with the **Call** *button* on it.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: Thank you very much times, this works for me. :)
best regards D0doooh

Comment: This worked for me on Catalina if I used the `tel://` scheme instead. The `facetime://` scheme opens a window of its own application with nothing in Notification Center.